# How to make ShadowCamera visible in three.js r73?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, shadow

```
Light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
```

gives a warning

```
THREE.Light: .shadowCameraVisible has been removed. Use new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow ) instead.
```

on adding

```
Scene.add(new THREE.CameraHelper(Light.shadow ));
```

gives an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix is not a function (three.js :35002)
```

Comment: Your seem to be intanciating the CameraHelper wrong. The constructor takes a Camera object, not a Light.

Comment: on giving camera object as input it not showing the shadow camera insted of it shows a x and y axis :)

Comment: This is the same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35171346/1697459). No answers there yet either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `CameraHelper` constructor takes a Camera object:

```
var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFAA55 );
light.castShadow = true;

var helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );
scene.add( helper );
```

Three.js r107

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvnc1g4y/