# ThreeJS shadows acting funny near walls

Tags: 3d, three.js, shadows

So I'm working with shadows in ThreeJS.  I'm using a Perspective Camera with WebGLRenderer.  The lighting settings are as such.

```
var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xdddddd, 1);
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, 1, 1, 2500));
light.shadow.bias = 0.0001;
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
light.position.set(100, 800, 0);
```

What I'm getting is a cut off shadow when I move close the wall.  I played with Shadow Bias however for me it's a total stab in the dark.

What I'm getting is this odd shadow behavior.  I've attached a screenshot and circled it in red along with an arrow pointing to it.  Notice how the shadow is cut off almost as though the light is reflecting off the wall and canceling out the shadow.  Any way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the shadow camera frustum is to narrow, use the [shadow camera helper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35178593/4977165) to inspect it and just try to increase it from ```60``` to lets say ```90```.

Comment: I think you're right since I did end up setting up the example as you pointed out.  I'm just unsure of how to set it up to be 90.

Comment: ```light.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1, 1, 2500));```

Comment: I eventually figured it out.  Thanks.  My light was 45 degrees off and too close.  Using the helper I adjusted it and all worked out great.  Write it up and I'll give you credit as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the shadow camera frustm is to narrow. You can check it by using the [shadow camera helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35178593/4977165):

```
var helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );
scene.add( helper );
```

The shadow camera is limited in size because of performance, but you can adjust every plane from it to suit your needs or just increase its angle (from 60 to 90 for example):

`light.shadow = new THREE.LightShadow(new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, 1, 1, 2500));`